# Groovy (Script Runner/Jira) Get WorkLog from Parent Issue to SubTask

Tags: groovy, jira

I have a problem with get "Time spent" from Parent Issue to SubTask.
Code below could get "Time spent" from WorkLog in Parent Issue to customfield with name "timeLogged", but I need set "Time spent" to Worklog not to customfield. Something like - Copy worklog from Parent Issue to Sub-Task.

```
def cfManager = ComponentAccessor.customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("timeLogged")
//timeLogged - customfield       
def changeHolder = new DefaultIssueChangeHolder()
cfManager.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(cfManager), parentIssue.getTimeSpent()),changeHolder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this - https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.1.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/worklog/WorklogManager.html :

....
    def worklog2 = new WorklogImpl(
        worklogManager,
        subtask,
        worklog.id,
        subtask.reporter.name,
        subtask.summary,
        new Date(),
        null,
        null,
        summ
    )
          worklogManager.update(subtask.reporter, worklog2, 0L, false)
      }
          }
....

And it works !! :)